# Sql Table design error

Tags: sql

I am trying to start learning Sql and in my boook head First c# i am making first sql server

but when i try to add the info about the humans it says this, please help.

> No row was updated.
>
> The data in row 1 was not committed. Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider. Error Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   "ContactID", table 'ContactDB.dbo.People'; column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated
>
> correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).

- in the code it says ContactID NO NULL but there is a error still..?= please help.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]

> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
>
> [ContactID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>
> [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL,

INSERT INTO [dbo].[People] ([ContactID], [Name], [Company], [Telephone], [Email], [Client], [LastCall]) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

it is like this in the sql

Comment: How have you created the table? I expect the column should have been defined as an `IDENTITY` column but has not been.

Comment: i created the table + all the infos buuuut.... when i go tabel design and add more info it says that error..

Comment: Hey man, the error message clearly said that, you try to insert a null value ina a column which marked as NOT NULL in sql server, you must provide a value when try to insert a row, or make it IDENTITY field.

Comment: if the column is defined as not null you need to insert a value to it or it needs to have a default contraint. The problem is that you probably don't understand what I am typing so please post some code you are using for people to help you

Comment: i am trying to set a name into nvarchar(100)

Comment: wht have you tried? Please provide some code..

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
(
 [ContactID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Company] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Telephone] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Email] NCHAR(100) NULL, 
    [Client] BIT NULL, 
    [LastCall] DATETIME NULL
) this is my table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] ( [ContactID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [Name] NCHAR(100) NULL,

Comment: Please **edit** your question instead of attempting to post code in comment. Comments are a poor place for code.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO People (ContactId,Name) VALUES(1,'John')
```

Will work

```
INSERT INTO People (Name) VALUES('John')
```

Will NOT work cos you need to provide the ContactId in the given table definition.

Comment: i just want to edit it in my "View Data" Cant i do that in the new visual studio?

Comment: Edit your question above and paste in some code you are using in VS so people see what you are actually doiong

Comment: Now i did it! that is my code a part of it the name table is same as all the other so this is the 2 main

Comment: Sorry but I understand the table you have but I need the code you are using to insert the data. First what kind of language are you going to programi in in Visual Studio?

Comment: i use c# + i am trying to just make the table in the start.